# How to get all the IPs(or username) from server of the clients connected to a shared print object?

Tags: c++, winapi, pywin32

**How to get all the IPs(or username) from server of the clients connected to a shared print object?**

Any help towards this direction would be great...Thank You..
Need help in Win 32 ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check [Print Spooler API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162861%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#print_job_functions) patriculary [EnumJobs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162625(v=vs.85).aspx) function.

Also check [FindFirstPrinterChangeNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162722(v=vs.85).aspx) function. You can create notification object for jobs and that way monitor who submited the job & what is printed on that printer.